# Common divisor of the form d = ax+by

Tags: arithmetic

There is a theorem that says that every pair of integers $a$ and $b$ has a common divisor $d$ of the form $d = ax+by$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Is it true that $d$ is also definitely the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$? Why is that so?

Comment: Not for $a=b=0$. And we want $d$ positive.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma

Answer (score 3):

Such *linear* common divisors are greatest: $\, c\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid ax+by = d\,\Rightarrow\, c\le d\ \ $  (if $d > 0)$

Comment: Is the second $\rightarrow$ true because if $c$ divides $d$, then $c \le d$ is necessarily true because the definition of $c$ divides $d$ is that $cn=d$ where $n$ is an integer (and not a fraction)? Also, the above explanation depends on the fact that $d$ actually divides $a$ and $b$ right?

Comment: @LateLearner  Yes, the definition of integer divisibility is used to deduce the inequality. That $\,d\mid a,b\,$ is not used above. It is essentially using that the set $\,c\,\Bbb Z\,$ of multiples of $\,c\,$ form an ideal, i.e. they are closed under addition, and under scaling by any integer. From this viewpoint the inference is $\,a,b\in c\,\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,ax,by\in c\,\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, ax+by\in c\,\Bbb Z.\ $

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true.  Once you have $d=ax+by$, you get $2d=(2a)x+(2b)y$ for free (or any other multiple).

Comment: I think the question almost explicitly specifies that $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I thought it was asking whether $d$ being representable by $ax+by$ implies $\rm{gcd}$.

Comment: What the question asks is a matter of interpretation. In any case, your answer adds useful information.